# Issue creating a dynamic array in Unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm following C# documentation on arrays but Unity does not let me create a dynamic array?

A static array works perfectly:

```
int[] numArray = new int[5] {};
```

A dynamic array:

```
int[] numArray = new int[] {};
```

returns "Type or end namespace definition, or end of file expect"

note: I'm a Javascript mechanic teaching students C# through Unity, I can think of lots of workarounds but I want to understand why Unity won't let me create a dynamic array or is it simply that C# or maybe Unity doesn't allow dynamic arrays to save memory?

Note2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
```

Comment: Well, you either need to supply the items that will be in the array `new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` or the length `new int[5];`. How else will it know how long the array needs to be (and arrays are fixed-length, so it does need to know this)? If you want an array that grows by itself, you want a `List<int>` or similar.

Comment: If you *do* want to create an empty array, you can just use `new int[0]`. But that's in no way a "dynamic array" - as @ProgrammingLlama says, arrays are *always* fixed-length after creation in C#.

Comment: Thanks, @JonSkeet & there is lots of C# websites that describes dynamic arrays in C#, for my own knowledge has the websites always been wrong or was there a version change? Defining the length makes sense from a memory perspective just never a requirement in JS so I have never had to think about it until now.

Comment: "there is lots of C# documentation that describes dynamic arrays in C#," Name one. There's no such thing as a dynamic array in C#. So which docs you refer to that uses that term?

Comment: Can you provide a link to such a documentation page? I'd be very surprised if you'd found anything official that stated anything like that. The only thing I can think of that comes close is `Array.Resize`, but that's basically making a new array and copying the data over.

Comment: Sorry, buy documentation I mean online websites, the documentation is too spare for my needs soi I'm following websites to deepen my knowledge I was just stumped by so many that say dynamic arrays are a thing in C# when clearly they are not. Thank you for your guidence

Comment: Again, can you link to such web sites? It's quite alarming to hear that reported, but without links to the actual sites, it's hard to know whether it might be a matter of you misunderstanding or whether they're just plain wrong. Arrays in C# have always, always, always had their lengths fixed at creation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **List** instead of an Array.

```cs
List<int> numList = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};
```

Similarly, C# offers different types of lists that are very efficient in memory management. For more information, see the link below.

[Microsoft.Com : Generic Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=net-7.0)